# Laravel - Second where not taking effect

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent

```
$from_date = Carbon::today();
$to_date =  Carbon::today();



$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', $from_date)
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $to_date)
            ->count();
```

I'm trying to create some reports. Today is one of the presets. The dates are as from_date & to_date variables. But the second column is always resulting in the record being 0.

There's two users who registered today, and once the second where is removed, I get the results.

Comment: you want to fetch all records of today's date?

Comment: In your case `$from_date` and `$to_date` are identical, so comparison does not make sense

Comment: Only for the today value, if the use clicks another preset value such as this week, the values will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your from and to dates to this:

```
$from_date = Carbon::today()->startOfDay();
$to_date = Carbon::today()->endOfDay();
```

Comment: what will be the value of `$from_date` and `$to_date`

Comment: date: 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00) and      date: 2018-10-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00),

respectively

Answer (score 0):

For results from today you can use

```
$users = User::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

To Check for date only use `->whereDate` method

```
$users = User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from_date)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to_date)
            ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $users = User::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->count();
```